# strange behavior using rbind with data.table (>= 1.13.0) in combination with data.frame

Tags: r, data.table

Trying to `rbind` a `data.table` containing an `IDate` (result of `fread`) to a `data.frame` containing a `character` converts the `IDate` to its internal integer representation. Probably this is by design, but if not it's a bug. `fread` supports `IDate` since `data.table` 1.13.0 (see https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md).

The example below shows that the `data.table` method of `rbind` can deal with it correctly (throw an error), but the `data.frame` method of `rbind` does not.

I don't know how and where this can/should be fixed.

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.frame(date = "2020-11-05")
dt1 <- data.table(date = "2020-11-05")
dt2 <- fread("date\n2020-11-05")
rbind(dt1, dt2) # ok -- throws error: rbind.data.table
#> Error in rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol): Class attribute on column 1 of item 2 does not match with column 1 of item 1.

## not ok -- converts int representation of IDate to character: rbind.data.frame
rbind(df1, dt2)
#>         date
#> 1 2020-11-05
#> 2      18571

## the other way round: ok -- throws an error: rbind.data.table
rbind(dt2, df1)
#> Error in rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol): Class attribute on column 1 of item 2 does not match with column 1 of item 1.

### solution
dt3 <- fread("date\n2020-11-05", colClasses = "character")
rbind(dt1, dt3)
#>          date
#> 1: 2020-11-05
#> 2: 2020-11-05
```

Created on 2020-11-05 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)

```
devtools::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
#>  os       Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  de_AT.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    de_AT.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       Europe/Vienna               
#>  date     2020-11-05                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date       lib source        
#>  assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  backports     1.2.0   2020-11-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  callr         3.5.1   2020-10-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  cli           2.1.0   2020-10-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  data.table  * 1.13.2  2020-10-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  devtools      2.3.2   2020-09-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  digest        0.6.27  2020-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  ellipsis      0.3.1   2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  fansi         0.4.1   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  fs            1.5.0   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  glue          1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  highr         0.8     2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  htmltools     0.5.0   2020-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  knitr         1.30    2020-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pkgbuild      1.1.0   2020-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  pkgload       1.1.0   2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  processx      3.4.4   2020-09-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  ps            1.4.0   2020-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  R6            2.5.0   2020-10-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  remotes       2.2.0   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  rlang         0.4.8   2020-10-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  rmarkdown     2.5     2020-10-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  stringi       1.5.3   2020-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  testthat      3.0.0   2020-10-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  usethis       1.6.3   2020-09-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  withr         2.3.0   2020-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  xfun          0.19    2020-10-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#> 
#> [1] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
#> [2] /usr/lib/R/site-library
#> [3] /usr/lib/R/library
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, the `rbind` gives no error for me. (Perhaps because the `fread` call you show here does not convert to `IDate` for me.) (I'm on R-4.0.2, data.table-1.13.0, win10)

Comment: @r2evans: if it is already a character nothing has to be converted and therefore it cannot be converted wrongly

Comment: DT can do nothing when you rbind using DF method, ultimate solution is to align classes of objects you are binding.

Comment: @jangorecki: I'm totally aware of it, therefore I posted the solution as well. Nevertheless I think it's worth to mention this behaviour somewhere to help other users.